# find & replace sing. char. in an ArrayList<String> element

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, arraylist

I am interested in iterating through (re: find and replace purposes),
say:

```
List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

where someList is already populated in an earlier method,
and consists of, say just a couple elements, in the fashion of, 
call it [a:bX, b:Xc],

where the find-and-replace String(s) of interest are, say:

```
String someString = "X";
String otherString = "Y";
String contentsTBD = "";
```

Now, ideally I thought I could've iterated over someList like so:

```
public void readAndReplace() {
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++) {
        if (someList.get(i).contains(someString)) {
            someList.get(i).replace(someString, otherString);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(someList);
}
```

wherein the printout should read:

```
[a:bY, b:Yc]
```

Then, I thought this might work:

```
public void readAndReplace() {
    for (String s : someList) {
        contentsTBD += s;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < contentsTBD.length(); i++) {
        if (contentsTBD.contains(someString)) {
            contentsTBD.replaceAll(someString, otherString);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
    System.out.print(contentsTBD);
}
```

but then quickly realized that this was nonsensical since
my reference to i was lost.  Any advice would be really helpful.
Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what's the problem with your first attempt.

Comment: `replace` doesnot modify the existing String. You need to re-assign the new string. Plus it will also not modify the list. You need to create a new list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- First, you are not storing your Replaced String anywhere. It is gone with the wind.
- Second, your replace will  not modify the existing list. You would need to set the new string into the existing location, since you are using traditional for-loop. **Or**, you can have a new list, and `add` modified values to that list.
- Remember, since `String` in Java is immutable, so all the methods of String class return a new string. They do not modify the existing one. So, you need to re-assign the returned String into a new one.

**Try out this code: -**

```
 public void readAndReplace()
    {
      // You can also create a new list out of the existing list.
      // That way, you won't need to modify the existing one.
      List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
      for(int i = 0; i < someList .size(); i++)
      {
          if(someList.get(i).contains(someString))
          {
              newList.add(someList.get(i).replace(someString, otherString));
             //someList.set(i, someList.get(i).replace(someString, otherString));
          } else {

              // If it not contains `someString`, add it as it is to newList
              newList.add(someList.get(i));
          }

       }
       System.out.println(someList);  // Original
       System.out.println(newList);   // New List

    }
```

Comment: +1 I liked the use two lists as an example, but you have updated the code, none-the-less, nice.

Comment: @MadProgrammer. I'll add it again.. I though we can set it into the existing list itself. So.

Comment: I just like the idea that your example provide a comparison between the lists, thought it was neat :)

Answer (score 7):

**Edited** added explanation,after the suggestion of MadProgrammer,

**Point 1**: `String` is `Immutable`, and you are trying to modify the string with `someList.get(i).replace(someString, otherString);` that will work, but not get reflected inside your `someList`, to reflect your someList you have to call the `someList.set(i)`

**Point 2**: 
Your `else` block is useless as you already `incrementing` the `i` inside the `for loop`

try this.

```
  String oldStr="";
    for (int i = 0; i < someList.size(); i++) {
        if (someList.get(i).contains(someString)) {
            oldStr = someList.get(i).replace(someString, otherString);
            someList.set(i, oldStr);
        } 
    }
    System.out.print(someList);
```

see how Immutable work in java [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)

Comment: Not that you answer is wrong (it's not), but why is it right?? ;)

Comment: @ MadProgrammer, String is Immutable, so it not get reflected with t changes made at someList.get(i).replace(someString, otherString);
line. I also added a link of immutable

Comment: Add the explanation to you answer and I will give you an up-vote ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks a lot for suggestion to add the explanation.

Comment: Much better :D - personally, better try and teach some one to fish

Comment: @ subodh you all give such thorough, precise help! Strictly excellent!

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is pretty old, but I was just looking for the same thing and figured I'd add what I found for the sake of others.

The easiest way I found to do this is with the ListIterator class which is a sub interface of Iterator that is meant for working specifically with Lists.  It makes this kind of operation pretty simple:

```
public void replace(List<String> list) {
    ListIterator<String> it = list.listIterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        it.set(it.next().replace("old_text","new_text"));
    }
}
```

It obviates the need to work with indices which is nice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that String is immutable, so it's not modified in-place in your List and you need to update it:

```
someList.set(i, someList.get(i).replace(someString, otherString);
```

You also don't need the else block, or you'll skip one more element.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem relates to the fact that strings are immutable (that is, there contents can't be changed).

This statement in your first example doesn't actually do anything...

```
someList.get(i).replace(someString, otherString);
```

I would probably do something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < someList .size(); i++)
{
    String value = someList.get(i);
    if(value.contains(someString))
    {

      value = value.replace(someString, otherString);

      someList.set(i, value);

    }
}
```

Also, I don't know why you are incrementing `i` in the else condition

Comment: Really, I gotta do more maths :P

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with first approach?
It should have worked if you remove the else block ('i' will already be incremented by for-loop).
Also, your second approach doesn't make sense, you are not using i inside the inner for loop, except to increment it, which should not be required(is it?)

Comment: The first approach will fail because strings are immutable and he's not replacing the values within in the list

Comment: oh yes, you are right! It will be required to put(replace) the new string  back in list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

1. Store the values within ArrayList first.
2. Use Iterator as you are using Generics.

   ```
   List<String> somelist = new ArrayList<String>();

   someList.add("Y");
   someList.add("X");
   someList.add("Z");

   Iterator itr = someList.iterator();
   while(itr.hasNext){
   String a = itr.next();
   String b = "Y";

   if(a.contains(b)){
   String c = b.replace("A");
   System.out.println(c);

   }
   else{
   System.out.println(b);

   }
   ```